# c# MVVM update Datagrid after combobox selection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I am creating a small wpf programme which filters a dataset by date.  It will eventually group and sum the data, but at the moment I am just trying to display the data rows.  I want a window with a `ComboBox`at the top with possible dates to select and a `DataGrid`showing the correct records.  I have bound the `ComboBox`to a list of possible dates, and I have bound a label to the value that the `ComboBox`updates.  This label updates when I select a value from the `ComboBox`.  I cannot however get the `DataGrid` to update to show the new data.

A `DataSet` is passed to the ViewModel constructor which extracts two `DataTables`. One is used to create an `ObservableCollection<DateTime>` for the `ComboBox`s items to bind to (through `WorkItemsDates`).  The other is stored for the `DataGrid` to bind to via a filtering (and eventually grouping/summing etc.) property `WorkItems`.  The `ComboBox` is bound to the `DateTime` `SelectedDate`.  The label is also bound to `SelectedDate` to ensure it is being updated by the `ComboBox`

The Xaml View is as follows:

```
<Window ...>
    <DockPanel>
        <ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding WorkItemsDates}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ItemStringFormat="ddd d MMM yyyy" 
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />

        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
               Content="{Binding SelectedDate, FallbackValue=99/99/9999}" 
               ContentStringFormat="dd MM yyyy" />

        <DataGrid Name="TimeTotalsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding WorkItems, Mode=OneWay}"            
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ></DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And code behind:

```
public partial class TheView: Window
{
    public UserControl1(DataSet tigerDataSet)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new TimeTotalsDateSelectorViewModel(tigerDataSet);
    }
}
```

The ViewModel is as follows:

```
internal class TimeTotalsDateSelectorViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<DateTime> _workItemsDates;
    private DataTable _workItems;
    private DateTime _selectedDate;

    public TimeTotalsDateSelectorViewModel(DataSet tigerDataSet)
    {
        if (tigerDataSet == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("workItemsDates");
        if (tigerDataSet.Tables["WorkItemsDates"] == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("tigerDataSet.Tables[WorkItemsDates]");
        if (tigerDataSet.Tables["WorkItems"] == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("tigerDataSet.Tables[WorkItems]");

        _workItems = tigerDataSet.Tables["WorkItems"];

        _workItemsDates = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>();
        foreach (DataRow row in tigerDataSet.Tables["WorkItemsDates"].Rows)
        {
            _workItemsDates.Add((DateTime)row["FinishDate"]);
        }

        SelectedDate = _workItemsDates[0];
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DateTime> WorkItemsDates 
    {
        get { return _workItemsDates; }
    }

    public DateTime SelectedDate 
    { 
        get { return _selectedDate; }
        set { _selectedDate = value; }
    }

    public DataTable WorkItems
    {
        get
        {
            DataRow[] _workItemsToShow = _workItems.Select("FinishTime>='" + _selectedDate.ToString() + "' AND FinishTime<'" + _selectedDate.AddDays(1).ToString() + "'");
            return _workItemsToShow.Count() != 0 ? _workItemsToShow.CopyToDataTable() : null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to implement the `IOnPropertyChange` interface. And once your combobox changes value, you have to apply a filter and reconstruct your dataset. In your code, the combobox update does not do anything...

Comment: interface INotifyPropertyChanged sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, as you are using `MVVM`, so you will have to notify your properties by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Second from the `Setter` of your `SelectedItem` property you will have to notify your `WorkItems` property as well, so that when you change the date from dropdown, it will also update the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`.

Comment: I Added:

`TimeTotalsDateSelectorViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }`
(no actual events/listeners yet) and the Label stopped updating...

Comment: Have you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`? If yes then make two calls to `OnPropertyChanged` method from `setter` of `SelectedItems` property. One by passing string "SelectedItems" and second by passing string "WorkItems"

Answer (score 0):

In the setter of SelectedDate, call the code that gets the values for the grid.  You should be implementing INotifyPropertyChanged as well, so the UI will update the data and the user can see it.